# Como fazer autenticação LDAP no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Bom dia

Estou precisando mudar o método de autenticação do Laravel para LDAP na minha empresa, mas não faço a mínima noção de onde e como proceder com as alterações. Fiz algumas pesquisas e não conseguir encontrar nada relacionado.

Alguém já passou por esse problema que possa me dar uma mão?

Comment: E qual o problema de instalar um pacote de terceiros? Algo como  `zendframework-zend-ldap` ou `symfony/ldap` (Symfony me parece apropriado desde que o próprio Laravel é composto de outros componentes Symfony)

Comment: Instalaria isso pelo composer?

Comment: http://tfs.amcom.com.br/Philips/PJ0714/_workItems?_a=edit&id=1189&triage=true simples assim

Comment: @IsaiasLima Certamente.

Comment: Vou dar uma verificada aqui nos conceitos, tentar alguns testes e retorno aqui